# C++ static members initialized with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, static, static-methods

Following is legal:

```
class FooAccesor {
  static std::function<void(Foo& foo)> getFooMethod() {
    return []() { foo.method(); };
  }
}
```

while

```
class FooAccesor {
  static const std::function<void(Foo& foo)> fooMethod = []() { foo.method(); };
}
```

is not. (Tried to fix with `constexpr` to no avail.) My MSVC compiler explained that `member of type const std::function<void(Foo& foo)> cannot have in-class initializer`. So I have to do something like

```
class FooAccesor {
  static std::function<void(Foo& foo)> fooMethod;
}
std::function<void(Foo& foo)> fooMethod = []() { foo.method(); };
```

My question is: why am I allowed to effectively initialize a method, while (as far as I can tell) I am not allowed to initialize static datamember?

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message. YOur example has more than one issue not directly related to the question. Missing `;` and what is `foo` you are trying to call a method on?

Comment: fixed missing semicolons; Foo is custom classtype; the code provided was meant as an illustration of language constraints rather than working example.

Comment: sorry for insisting, but to demonstrate what you wanted to demonstrate you could have added a dummy `Foo` definition, fixed the typos and included the resulting compiler error. Often a [mcve] needs only 1 or 2 lines of code added, but it helps a lot to avoid confusion. Eg I wasnt 100% sure if your "I am not allowed" is also due to the type of the lambda you want to assign is of wrong type. I had to do a little of guess work. Nevermind, I think i guessed right.

Comment: You did, and thanks for the tips (next time will provide more complete sample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to declare the member as [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) (since C++17). And you have to fix several typos in your example (missing `;` and not passing a `Foo` to the lambda):

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo { void method(){}};

class FooAccesor {
  inline static std::function<void(Foo& foo)> fooMethod = [](Foo& foo) { foo.method(); };
};
```